# How to force systemd enter in emergency mode?

Tags: opensuse, systemd

I'm using Opensuse 12.3.
systemd-195-13.45.1.x86_64

After few problems when I added a disc at btrfs mount I'm trying put my system in emergency mode (which I consider all services will be stopped and all mounts able to be unmounted),.

But they just don't work!!!

**How to force systemd enter in emergency mode?** (or something equivalent of init single mode)
and force the emergency mode at boot time(grub menu)?

**First attempt:**
I use the old way : `init 1` at the console...
They show me the emergency screen , ask for root password, but after this re-login, I still unable to unmount my btrfs FS (says it are in use).
(with lsof I don't found anything using this mounts).
The `runlevel` command return level 3... not 1...

**Second attempt:**
I run the command `systemctl emergency` which show me the "emergency screen" , ask for root password... and then finally show me runlevel = 1 . But I'm still not able to umount my btrfs FS....

**Third attempt:**
I reboot the machine and at grub screen I type 'e' to add the "emergency" word at the options. Where they give me a message like "emergency word is invalid".
I try with "single" word and get the same behave....

---

My final solution was remove the automatically mount from fstab and reboot my system at normal mode. Then finally I able to run my check at btrfs Fs... but is very annoying because all services which depends this mount start give errors...

Comment: check the system logs - `init 1` is not working so there must be something serious going on.

Comment: You haven't described the nature of the original problem.  If the system *can't* unmount the disk for some kind of weird reason, it can't unmount the disk.  Switching runlevels may be intended to *try* and do certain things, but emergency mode is not *"automatically fix all my problems mode"*.  So: you'd be better off asking a question describing your problems with the disk, not systemd, etc.

Comment: Hi @goldilocks, I don't want the emergency mode to "solve all problems", but as they own name says it's for emergency! Considering this I suppose they should be capable to force all services/process out to free any mount system... (at least, years ago the `init 1` always solves this for me). Will be useful to know if the `systemctl emergency` should be attend situations like that (or I should use other mode?) and at any tip how to force it at next reboot and avoid at boot time anyone use the FS before I execute my stuffs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4 targets in systemd. what you wanted is emergency.target
I think you can try these steps:

1. reboot the system
2. interrupt the boot loader menu countdown by pressing any key
3. move the cursor the entry to be started
4. press **e** to edit the current entry
5. move the cursor tho the entry to the line that starts with **linux16**. This is the kernel command line.

6.append **systemd.unit=desired.target**

7. press **ctrl+x** to boot with these changes.

This is rhel7's method . I think it is maybe similar with suse .
Once you enter into emergency mode, root password is still needed.
good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

After read the comments of @suspectus and @goldilocks , although already "solve" my original problem with the btrfs, I tested again putting my system in emergency mode.

I considering have misunderstand the difference between *emergency* mode of **systemd** with *single mode* of **SystemV**.
But as I don't have sure about my answer and about my understand... so, **I will not check my answer as correct for now.**

The emergency mode, close and shutdown all services for good and not change the runlevel and not dismount any volume/FS.

---

*About my root problem* which trick my mind, where I think not entered in emergency mode berfore...

Discover I will not be capable to umount my FS because I need to umount it with `systemctl` command:

```
systemctl stop dados.mount
```

Where "dados" is my btrfs FS /dados.  Then they dismount effectively.
The weird thing, there is no way to identify why the `unmount` command inform the FS is "in use" and nothing is showed at `lsof` command.
*Probably some internal latch between the umount/systemd...*

Comment: The "in use" error could also happen if there are sub-mounts under the btrfs mount point.  Looking at `man systemd.mount` and `man systemd`, systemd might be handling that automatically.