# How to rescue Ubuntu Server 16.04 which is getting shut down by systemd script?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, systemd, startup

I wrote a program which automatically shuts down a Raspberry Pi 3b (Ubuntu Server 16.04) as soon as a button is pressed. It's nothing than a small bash script which reads a GPIO pin of the Pi every second and shuts down the device if the button is pressed.

However, I made a mistake and the condition is always true, meaning that the program shuts down the Pi as soon as it is started. Because of incredible stupidness, I already linked this program to systemd ('After=multi-user.target'). Meaning: as soon as the Pi finished booting, it shuts itself down again. I don't see any chance to interrupt this process. Is there a way to edit the '/boot/config.txt' in a way that certain 'systemd' processes are suppressed? Any other idea how I could fix this system? On my Mac I only see the boot partition and my Linux computer has no SD Card slot.

P.S.: I flashed one of these images to the SD card in the beginning https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/ using 'dd'.
P.S.2: Shutdown is initialized by 'poweroff'

Comment: Common sense says it is time to buy an adapter.

Comment: Have you tried forcing the system to boot into a different systemd target other than multi-user ?  Check this answer which describes setting it up during boot. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252953/151609

Comment: The thing was that I somehow could not interrupt the boot process by key combinations. Not sure if this is a Pi specific thing.

Comment: SD card adapter is ordered ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With systemd for init, systemd's rescue target can be reached by appending  `systemd.unit=rescue.target` (or `emergency.target` if that fails) to the boot command line in `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

If this doesn't work for some reason, or on a non-systemd system, instead add `init=/bin/sh` to the end of the line, which will cause the system to completely bypass anything to do with init.

You may need to mount the filesystem read-write in order to make any modifications. You may do this by appending `rw` to the boot command line, or issue `mount -o remount,rw /` upon boot.

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for! By adding `init=/bin/sh` to `/boot/cmdline.txt` I could edit my script after remounting the sd card by `mount -o remount.rw /`. Thanks a million, you saved my day / week!

Comment: This answer is the wrong way around.  Rescue and emergency modes, with `-s` and `-b` and their various synonyms, are the right first and second things to try, whereas `init=/bin/sh` is a poor idea for the reasons explained at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197472/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195978/5132 and should be a third choice, if used at all.  [The systemd doco also says this.](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#bootingintorescueoremergencytargets)

Answer (score 0):

systemd scan kernel argument .
to disable for example  **cron.service** add to your boot loader:

```
systemd.mask=cron.service
```

If you have access to config.txt , you must modify to cmdline.txt .

Source :

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/boot.md

Source :
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/kernel-command-line.html